# Operation on character in java

Tags: java, string, character, operation

i have this method :

```
public static String appliquerCoup( String combinaison, String coup ){
    String res = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        res = res + (combinaison.charAt(i) - coup.charAt(i));
    }
    return res;
}
```

if i apply this in the main

```
System.out.println(appliquerCoup("414", "020")
```

i have :

```
4-14
```

As logical as it is, it's puting me a `-1` for `2-1 = -1`
I want it to put me 0 if the operation is inferior to 0.

So i made these changes :

```
public static String appliquerCoup( String combinaison, String coup ){
    String res = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        char cFinal = combinaison.charAt(i) - coup.charAt(i);
        if(cFinal < '0')
        cFinal = 0;
        res = res + cFinal;
    }
    return res;
}
```

but it is saying me that on the 4th line that there's

```
possible loss of precision
found :int; required: char
```

Can you help me find the solution ? It's been a long i'm trying.

Thanks so much

Comment: Try casting your characters to integers. Performing a character minus character operation doesn't make a whole lot of sense. I'm also not sure what you're trying to do... If you could please elaborate on that.

Comment: To explain :
What i wanna do is the following :
for example : i wanna substract 020 on 414... The result expected is 404.
You're gonna understand that u substract the 1st number with the first, the 2nd with the 2nd and the 3rd with the 3rd... If a substraction is negative, it has to return 0.
Is it clear ?

Comment: You are very confident in your inputs there; do you really expect input strings with only digits in them?

Comment: @khelwood find the solution, thank you guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of subtracting one character from another is an integer. It tells you the distance between them.

Imagine you were calculating `'b' - 'a'`. The difference between them is the number `1`, not the character `'1'`.

You can change `cFinal` to an `int` and it should work, since it's legal to append integers to a string:

```
int cFinal = combinaison.charAt(i) - coup.charAt(i);
if (cFinal < 0) // NB: compare with 0, not '0'
    cFinal = 0;
res = res + cFinal;
```

Or you can use [`max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)) to enforce the lower bound more succinctly.

```
res += Math.max(0, combinaison.charAt(i) - coup.charAt(i));
```

Comment: If i change cFinal to an int, the result give me a 000...
I don't know why

Comment: @biiwop Did you change `if (cFinal < '0')` to `if (cFinal < 0)` ?